# How to just get the icon to spin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, favicon

I'm playing around with bootstrap and trying to just get the icon spin with the text staying still but still inside the button tag.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>


 <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary"><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up fa-spin'>Like</i></button>
    </div>
```

Comment: `<button class="btn btn-block btn-primary"><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up fa-spin'></i>Like</button>` should do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove text from the icon maker :)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>


 <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary"><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up fa-spin'></i>Like</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put the text outside the `i` tag

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>


 <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary"><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up fa-spin'></i>Like</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy as this

```
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
```

And if you want your icons to spin in reverse while maintaining browsers' support use this

```
.fa-spin-reverse {
  -webkit-animation: fa-spin-reverse 2s infinite linear;
  animation: fa-spin-reverse 2s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fa-spin-reverse {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
@keyframes fa-spin-reverse {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace button code with this code :

`<button class="btn btn-block btn-primary"><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up fa-spin'></i>Like</button>`

**Note:** Always keep text outside from the `i` tag while using icons libraries